# How to use system variable in CMakeCache.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

so I have project that generates CMakeCache.txt, which sets a lot of variables like:

```
project_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=/home/username/project
```

and I would like to replace `/home/username` by system variable $HOME, how should I do that? would below work?

```
project_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=$HOME/project
```

or

```
project_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=$ENV{HOME}/project
```

Comment: The cache is actually just a text file, CMakeCache.txt, that gets created in the build directory when you run CMake. This is how CMake remembers anything you set, so you don't have to re-list your options every time you rerun CMake.

Comment: I understand that but i am trying to sync mac and linux for the same project using the same CMakeList.txt. and the issue is $HOME in mac is different from $HOME in linux, the generated CMakeCache.txt does not work for both platform. in CMakeList i can use $ENV{HOME} to address this, is there a way to carry over this variable of HOME to CMakeCache.txt when it got generated?

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CACHE.html#cache), it's may be of use to you.

Comment: No, `CMakeCache.txt` stores the plain content of the variables, so `$HOME` is treated literally, and the `$ENV{HOME}` too. The build directory (where `CMakeCache.txt` and other CMake-generated files reside) can only be used **on the same machine** where it has been created. When you want to use the project on another machine, you need to **configure it for that machine**. Exception could be for the machines with the very same layout of system tools and other things, but Mac and Linux are definitely not the same. And I am pretty sure that difference in `HOME` is not the only one.